# Является ли рекурсией вызов иного метода/функции из данного метода?

Tags: функции, рекурсия

В процессе работы над программой, мною был создан генератор объектов, который, помимо прочих параметров, мог принимать в качестве аргумента функцию. Каждый объект, сгенерированный таким конструктором по итогу обладал своей собственной функцией.

Исполняемый код создаёт эти самые объекты. В процессе создания, каждый генерируемый объект, вызывает заложенную в него функцию, а та, в свою очередь, может вызвать любые иные функции.

**По итогу возник следующий вопрос**: если рекурсия это вызов метода самим собой, то является-ли вызов любой иной функции данным методом рекурсией?

Вопрос возник из-за того, что при использовании рекурсии генерируется и стек рекурсии, который запоминает результаты каждого отдельного вызова рекурсивного метода и, в случае переполнения стека рекурсии, компилятор/интерпретатор прекращает исполнение кода. По сему хотелось бы разобраться, является-ли вызов какого-либо иного метода, текущим методом, рекурсией и возникает-ли что-то подобное стеку рекурсии при вызове методом сторонних методов.

Comment: Если функция 1 вызывает функцию 2, а функция 2 вызывает функцию 1 - это [взаимная рекурсия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F)

Comment: @insolor, а если функция 1 вызывает функцию 2, а та вызывает функцию 3? То есть любая текущая функция может вызывать только другие, ранее не вызываемые функции?

Comment: Только если функция 3 вызывает одну из предыдущих функций или саму себя) А так - нет.

Comment: @insolor, благодарю вас за ответ! Считаю его решением по данному вопросу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Рекурсия - это определение чего-то через само себя. В программировании - это вызов функцией самой себя, также возможна [взаимная рекурсия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F), когда две или более функций вызывают друг друга.

Тут удобно представить последовательность вызовов функций в виде графа: если граф вызовов не содержит циклов (например, если он линеен или может быть представлен в виде дерева), то рекурсии нет.

Судя по описанию вашей проблемы в конце вопроса, я предполагаю, что у вас в коде все-таки возникла рекурсия, возможно из-за какой-то ошибки в коде.